# Python: convert dictionary from swiplserver

Tags: python, json, prolog, swi-prolog

I am using swiplserver for using prolog queries in python. Within that queries I get dictionaries of this kind:

```
to_translate = {'A': 'p', 'B': '_', 'C': 'q', 'Z': {'→E': {'args': [['p', {'args': ['p', 'q'], 'functor': '→'}], 'q'], 'functor': '⊦'}}}
```

In the prolog file I just defined some xfy [operators](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators) (e.g. ⊦ and →). My aim now is to translate the dictionary in the following way (is the same as the natural output of prolog would give me):

```
result = {'A': 'p', 'B': '_', 'C': 'q', 'Z': {'→E': '[p, (p → q)] ⊦ q'}}
```

If ⊦ wouldn't be in the list of my operators, the result would be:

```
result = {'A': 'p', 'B': '_', 'C': 'q', 'Z': {'→E': '⊦([p, (p → q)], q)'}}
```

I've heard swiplserver uses JSON to generate the dictionaries itself. Maybe that is the key and the problem is much easier to solve as I think.

Hope you can give me some quick tip or some solution about that.

Comment: Why not just look at the [MQI source code](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-mqi).

Comment: Of interest: [term_to_json_string](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-mqi/blob/master/mqi.pl#L952-L960)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But I think this function only works in the direction prolog term to json string. E.g. ´term_to_json_string([p, q],A).´ works well and I become the correct output  `A = "[\"p\", \"q\" ]\n".`In the other direction, means  ´term_to_json_string(A,"[\"p\", \"q\" ]\n").´  my result in swi prolog is only false.

Comment: What I don't understand is why are you asking swiplserver questions on StackOverflow. The creator of the technology is communicating with you on the SWI-Prolog forum and Jan W. is also there to see the questions and chime if needed and fix SWI-Prolog if needed.

Comment: Thanks, that is for sure little strange. I'd like to store some key answers here, so I posted it on this community. An I was thinking there is already some very easy solution to solve this. But I'm thinking about to post some question in SWI-Prolog forum too. This with a more general approach ... :) I will inform here, if new things are happening on there.

Comment: Thanks. Would hate to see you NOT get an answer by only posting here. I only see Jan W. answer here once in a blue moon and don't recall ever seeing Eric Z. here.

Comment: `I will inform here, if new things are happening on there.` FYI I am EricGT on the SWI-Prolog forum and one the admind there. I will probably delete this comment tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how to convert the JSON format returned by [swiplserver](https://pypi.org/project/swiplserver/) into a Prolog string?

There is a `swiplserver` function `json_to_prolog` that will do this, but it currently only generates terms like `+(b, c)` as opposed to `b + c` which is not quite what you're looking for, but may be helpful?

```
from swiplserver import *

print(json_to_prolog({'args': [['p', {'args': ['p', 'q'], 'functor': '→'}], 'q'], 'functor': '⊦'}))
```

Running that gives:

```
'⊦'([p, '→'(p, q)], q)
```